# Why is mypy not following imports in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy

I am working in VSCode with a virtual env at `.venv`. I have installed `mypy` there. I have a `TypedDict` class in one module that will flag errors in VSCode in the same file:

```
class File(TypedDict):
    id: int
    title: str

### mypy flags this:
x: File = {"idx": 1}
```

BUT when I import this class to another file/module, VSCode does NOT flag such an error. Why not? I've tried all sorts of settings; here's where I left it:

```
### .vscode/settings.json
{
  "python.formatting.autopep8Path": ".venv/bin/autopep8",
  "python.linting.mypyPath": ".venv/bin/mypy",
  "python.linting.mypyArgs": [
    "--follow-imports=error",
    "--ignore-missing-imports",
    "--show-column-numbers",
    "--no-pretty"
  ],
  "python.linting.mypyCategorySeverity.note": "Error",
  "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true
}
```

I have also tried playing with a `mypy.ini` file in the root dir to no avail :(

Comment: What does your `mypy.ini` file look like?

Comment: It had all sorts of variations before I gave up, removed it, and tried just using the settings in .vscode/settings.json

Comment: Nevermind -- I had put `__init__` instead of `__init__.py`. Will delete question.